# My Lumia 520 phone is faulty.Its going on flight mode

Tags: 8.1, functionality, flight-mode

My phone is going into the flight mode. I tried to restart it,but it's still going into flight mode. I can only use it over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Have you considered taking it to a service centre?

Comment: Try Hard Resetting your phone. If that does work take it to service centre. However check mobile & sim option in setting. Try updating system apps from store.