# Continous flight mode ON in my lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520, flight-mode

I' am having an issue with my lumia 520, I own a few different windows phones of my interests. 1 lumia 520, 2 lumia 625 and 1 lumia 1020. I can find that all other phones are functioning perfectly. Except for my lumia 520. I have tried the following steps as soon as i saw the flight mode Enabled by default;

1. Disable flight Mode - Unsuccessful
2. Reset phone = Settings -> About -> Reset phone - Unsuccessful
3. Hard Reset = Power on + Volume down -> Volume up+Volume down+Power+Volume Down - Unsuccessful
4. Windows phone Recovery Tool - Connect -> download -> RESET / Flash Phone with latest updated windows operating system - Unsuccessful.
5. Changed my sim to another phone - working fine
6. Inserted another sim into my Lumia 520 - Unsuccessful

I tried surfing in most of the gadget sites and recovery sites where in all that is present is what i did.

All I need to know is that - Is there any other ways using which i would be able to get my phone back to life? I' am totally out of ideas to go on with bringing it back to life. I' am in need of suggestions / solved solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13087/106